# Lineno line numbers render incorrectly with 2 columns, Polyglossia and RTL language

Tags: polyglossia, right-to-left, lineno

I'm trying to produce a 2-column paper with line numbers on the sides using the *lineno* package. However, I need to include some examples written in a right-to-left language (Urdu in my case, but any RTL language seems to cause the same problem).

As soon as I include a RTL language in `\setotherlanguages` for the *polyglossia* package, the line numbering breaks: numbers in the second column aren't to the right of that column as they should be, but they end up in the middle of the page, overlapping with text.

Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm,heightrounded=true]{geometry}

\usepackage[switch,mathlines]{lineno}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{urdu}  % this is what breaks the line numbers
\linenumbers


\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Note that it doesn't actually contain any Urdu text, just the *polyglossia* setting.

This is what gets produced (note the line numbers in the middle):
[image: Lorem ipsum with line numbers overlapping text]

And this is the desired output (swap `urdu` for `french` or any LTR language to get it):
[image]

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `bidi` package is trying to make sure that the numbers are typeset at the correct margin by adding the following code to the `begindocument` hook:

```
  \if@RTLmain
    \rightlinenumbers*
  \else
    \leftlinenumbers*
  \fi
  \@ifpackagewith{lineno}{left}{%
    \leftlinenumbers*
  }{}
  \@ifpackagewith{lineno}{right}{%
    \rightlinenumbers*
  }{}
```

so one of the macros `\rightlinenumbers*`, or `\leftlinenumbers*` is used and overrides the `switch` option. You can fix that by switching back to the mode you want at the beginning of the document:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm,heightrounded=true]{geometry}

\usepackage[switch,mathlines]{lineno}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{urdu}  % this is what breaks the line numbers
\linenumbers
\AtBeginDocument{\switchlinenumbers} %% <------ new

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks – this worked!